# Can a world save mods?

Tags: space-engineers

Every time i open a world, the game downloads all mods used in this world. Its nice to have them up to date, but is there a way to let the world save these mods and update them only when necessary? It takes a relatively long time to download them and not everybody has fast internet or mods could get deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are we speaking about Single or Multiplayer?

If it's Singleplayer: So far I know you don't redownload the mods everytime you load the world its just loading them from your workshop downloads. But when a mod updates, the updated files will be downloaded from Steam's download manager. Just as if you're downloading DLC or a complete game, it will show "Space Engineers - Workshop Content" in your download list.

If it's Multiplayer: MP is a different case, everytime you join a server it will redownload the mods used on that server as long you're not subscribed to those mods. Just subscribe on said mods on Steam Workshop and you don't redownload the mods every single time you join the server.